# I can't see in the list of TeamCity - Allure Report Generation

Tags: teamcity, allure

I installed the plug-in in accordance with the instructions. And it appears in the list. http://funkyimg.com/i/U6ju.png But when I want to configure Build Feature, in the drop-down list it does not exist http://funkyimg.com/i/U6jH.png

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We developed this plugin using Teamcity API 8.0. Please check whether your Teamcity version is 8.0+.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have TeamCity 9.0.1. Is this version of Allure not supported version 9.0.1?

Comment: Please create an issue under https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity-plugin so we could investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have plugin sources installed instead of plugin binaries:

- Version and Vendor values not fetched from plugin xml descriptor;
- Plugin name contains 'master' (branch name).

It's common problem due to 'Download ZIP' (means sources, positioned under git/svn urls) button on github repositories pages.

Ensure you are following [instructions](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity-plugin#installation) and download plugin from [releases page](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity-plugin/releases)